# Explicit casting for a loop

Tags: java, loops, casting, double

"Write a program that reads a double value from the user and store it in a double variable. It will then perform an explicit casting to assign it to a float variable. You will then compute the absolute value of the difference between these two variables. Do so in a loop, while this difference is below a threshold that was initialized to 1.0 before the loop. At the end of each iteration, decrease the threshold by dividing it by 10.0."

I was given this example to work out for my java class and I'm able to get as far as reading and storing the double variable but I'm lost on the "explicit casting to assign it to a float variable". I've yet to understand what explicit casting is/does since my textbook barely even defines it so more than anything I'd like a definition of what is does and how exactly to code it in a way the question wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to java coding.

Type casting means to assign a variable to a new type even if it was predefined.

Take an Double

```
double number = 4.5;
```

Now you gonna store that number as integer.

```
int falsyNumber = number;
```

This will produce an error, because your integer is not capable of storing values behind the decimal point. The compiler will propably stop execution by default and call sth. like "you gonna lose information if you do that, is it intentional?"

Therefor you need to say "YES, I dont care about those lost data and need that extra space of memory that i can free with that.."

So you have to explicitly typecast that variable to be Integer.

```
int falsyNumber = (int)number;
```

The brackets hold the type, and number is used as it was of that type (in this line at least).
So your compiler wont show an error here, but your output will be `4`, because you lose that data than can obviously not be stored by integer.

Many words, for such an easy line. You typecast your double value and store it into (another) variable of the type float.

```
double input = 3.983243242423;                   // that is your input stored
float numberToCalulateWith = (float)input;       // here it truncates eventually
```

It is to be said, in some cases the difference wont be that noticeable. Because you stored a "4" as double and then cast it to float you will still have a 4. But if its not such an easy number you will lose data, and the goal of this exercise is to see, from when on you lose it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely understand the concept a lot more clearly now.

Comment: Follow [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `FalsyNumber` should be `falsyNumber`.

Comment: Thanks alot, autocorrection took care of it. Changed it for sure.